# Spring MongoDB composite indexing coverage

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, indexing, mongodb-indexes

I have a document that has fields `engine`, `type`, `manufacturerId`. I created a composite `unique` index on the 3 fields, so I used the following to create the index.

```
@CompoundIndex(name = "engine_type_manufacturerId", def = "{'engine' : 1, 'type' : 1, 'manufacturerId': 1}", unique = true)
```

This does the job to avoid duplicate entries for the combination of the 3 fields.

Moving on, in my application I have queries where I would search by `engine` only or `engine & type`. Now, my question is, will the composite unique index that I created earlier cover the cases for the queries on `engine` or `engine & type` OR should I create new indexes for those?

Comment: Check out the doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes

Comment: Thanks. `tl;dr`, it does cover for `engine` or `engine & type`